# Wordpress Twenty Eleven PhP - forcing php code to skip first post on homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: What I want to fix]

I have set up my Wordpress to add the [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)  to all posts on the homepage.

How do I make the code skip adding [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) to the first post [the_content() ~ in the code below] and only add them to [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) the other posts [the_excerpt() ~ in the code below]?

Code I put in content.php to make it put [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) on homepage. [Link Here](http://pastebin.com/xWPWY5UA)

```
    <?php if ( is_search() | is_home() ) : // Edit this to show excerpts in other areas of the theme?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
    <!-- This adds the post thumbnail/featured image -->
        <div class="excerpt-thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?></a></div>
                      <?php  if($wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged()) { the_content(); } else { the_excerpt(); }     ?>                     


            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple - you just use the opposite of the logic that you use in order to figure out whether to display the full content or just the excerpt.

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() ) : // Edit this to show excerpts in other areas of the theme?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php if ( $wp_query->current_post != 0 || is_paged() ) : // Don't display the thumbnail if it's the first post... ?>
            <!-- This adds the post thumbnail/featured image -->
            <div class="excerpt-thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && ! is_paged() ) {
            the_content();
        } else {
            the_excerpt();
        } ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

PS: I know it's quite irrelevant, but please, **please** try to have a cleaner code :) Take a look at the [WordPress PHP Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/) to familiarize yourself with them. It makes reading through code a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Define a counter and for the first time don't show the featured image.

```
<?php $counter++; if ($counter!=1) the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just verify if is first post or not

```
$firstPost = true;
while() // loop for posts
if(!$firstPost){
//your code for adding thumbnail
}
else{
$firstPost = false;
}
```

Comment: please don't forget indentention